# ruby on rails how to add files to a folder for direct use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, upload, directory

I want to add some `.c files`  **manually** in my website for others to be able to see them with a direct link in their browser...

Where do i add these files and how can i link to them in a view file?

Do i simply create a folder in the assets or in the root of the site and link manually like

`http://www.mysite.com/path/to/file`?

is it possible to make this use routes **like**

`this_route_path()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your files in `public` directory in your rails project, it will be available to world. And if configured, the front end servers (web servers) can directly serve them without loading rails stack.

For example, if you keep `test.txt` in `public` directory, you can access it like `http://127.0.0.1:3000/test.txt`. You can make your own directory structure inside the public directory and format the URL accordingly.

Comment: OMG that makes so much sense... really forgot about public folder